# java -version don't want to load my new value of Java_home

Tags: java, cmd

When I run in my cmd :

```
java -version 

java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

but I just edited my Java_HOME and my path to a new value :

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Users\Me\Documents\JDK\jdk-11.0.6
```

Why my java version is still 1.8.0 ?

Comment: %JAVA_HOME% is irrelevant, what is on your path?

Comment: @DavidConrad I have in my path : %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: I guarantee you you have another entry in your PATH that also has java.exe in it, and that comes before that.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes you right ! it works now !